# Error trying to get command status with aws cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I seem to keep getting an error whenever I try to use bash to automate getting the status of a job.
My current bash script currently looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids=$1; 
start=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id $1)
status=$(echo $start | jq '.InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceState.Name')

#wait for ec2 instance to start running before launching command
while [ "$status" != "\"running\"" ]
do
  start=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id $1)
  status=$(echo $star | jq '.InstanceStatueses[0].InstanceState.Name')
done


sh_command_id=$(aws ssm send-command --instance-ids=$1 --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters 'commands=["echo Helloworld","sleep 60"]');
command_id=$(echo $sh_command_id | jq '.Command.CommandId')

full_status=$(aws ssm list-commands --command-id $command_id)


echo $command_id;
 

aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids=$1;
```

When the script gets to `aws ssm list-commands --command-id $command_id` I get this error.

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListCommands operation: 2 
validation errors detected: Value '"67fb9aed-00bf-4741-ae1a-736ddbfba498"' at 'commandId' 
failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[A-Fa-
f0-9]{8}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}$.; Value 
'"67fb9aed-00bf-4741-ae1a-736ddbfba498"' at 'commandId' failed to satisfy constraint: 
Member must have length less than or equal to 36.
```

When running everything individually in terminal I get the same error. However, I do not get an error when I mannually type in the commandId as so: `full_status=$(aws ssm list-commands --command-id 67fb9aed-00bf-4741-ae1a-736ddbfba498)`.

Is there some aws formatting I am missing here?

Comment: Your data has literal double quotes. You can use `jq -r` to have jq output raw strings instead of JSON tokens

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to avoid the use of `jq` by using the  aws cli built in `--query 'your.json.query'` to specify your JSON query and then the `--output text` to return plain text.    It has been a while since I checked so your mileage may vary.

I was able to verify that the following works for checking an ec2 is running:

```
check_instance() {
    local instance_id="${1}"
    local status="_"
    while [ "${status}" != "running" ] ; do 
        status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status \
            --instance-ids ${instance_id} \
            --query "InstanceStatuses[*].InstanceState.Name" \
            --output text)
    done

    echo "${instance_id} is running"
}
```